# ASP.net dowload/export without using HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know there are a lot of questions about downloading and exporting files from an asp.net website, but they all end up with the same answer.  My website gives users the option to download files and export data to an excel spreadsheet.  Currently, I am using the solution everyone seems to provide which looks like this:

```
public void ExcelExport(System.Data.DataTable dtData, String strFileName)
{
    try
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileName);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = GetMIMEType(Path.GetExtension(strFileName));

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(BuildStringWriter(dtData));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("ExcelExport() Failed: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This is the method I call to export data, and my download method is almost identical.  The problem is that it I cannot show a spinner or waiting message because I have no way of closing either one once the export/download is completed. There are also other tasks I would like to execute after exporting/downloading, but I currently cannot.

So, my question is: is there another means for my client's to download files and export data without using HttpContext?  Also, I would prefer not having reference a dll that I would have to download.

Thanks

Comment: is the excel export a xls file or can it be a csv? If it can be a csv, and you are using page data to export to excel, you can easily do it client side. Another thing you can do is just send the bytes over to the client and process them client side.

Comment: To be clear, it's not HttpContext you have a problem with. Rather it's closing/ending the response.

Comment: @Rick The export file is an xls.  I am working on another way of exporting the data, but my issue remains for files that my clients will need to download.  I need to make sure the export and download works on as many browsers, so I cannot rely on the download attribute.  I am not familiar with converting the files/data to bytes and sending that to client side, but I will look into that.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Every HTTP Request only have one HTTP Response, you can choose only if you want it to be a file download or another web page.

Using or not HttpContext have nothing to do with it.

That said, you can redirect the user to a download page, that triggers the download after x amount of seconds (as most download sites do)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have tried redirecting users to another page to handle the download, but I had issues on IE with that method.  I cannot remember what the issue was, but I remember my boss telling me that he did not like the way it behaved and preferred the current method.  It is possible I did something wrong, so I will have to look into it again.  Also, thanks for clearing up my misunderstanding of HttpContext.